# ARFIMA model and accurancy function

Tags: r, forecast

I am foresting with data sets from fpp2 package and forecast package. So my intention is to make automatic forecasting with a several time series. So for that reason I am forecasting with function.  You can see code below:

```
#  CODE
library(fpp2)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

df<-qauselec

# Forecasting function         
fct_fun <- function(Z, hrz = forecast_horizon) {
  timeseries <- msts(Z, start = 1956, seasonal.periods = 4)
  forecast <- arfima(timeseries)
}  
acc_list <- lapply(X = df, fct_fun)
```

So next step is to check accuracy of model. So for that reason I am trying with this line of code you can see below

```
accurancy_arfima <- lapply(acc_list,  accuracy)
```

Until now this line of code or function accuracy worked perfectly with other models like snaive,ets etc. but with arfima  can’t work properly.
So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem with accuracy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow R-documentation, Returns range of summary measures of the forecast accuracy. If x is provided, the function measures test set forecast accuracy based on x-f . If x is not provided, the function only produces training set accuracy measures of the forecasts based on f["x"]-fitted(f).
And usage summary can be seen :

```
accuracy(f, x, test = NULL, d = NULL, D = NULL,
  ...)
```

So :

```
accuracy(acc_list[[1]]$fitted, df)
```

If you want to evaluate separately accuracy, It will work.

```
a <- c() 
for (i in 1:4) {
  b <- accuracy(df[i], acc_list[[1]]$fitted[i])
  a <- rbind(a,b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.I try this, but this line of code works  only with data  with one time series.Аs I mentioned above my intention is to work with several time series (e.g df<-uschange[,1:4] this is example with four time series), so please correct if is possible?

Comment: Why not. I added answer.